# Hive Xml serDe Creating a Table

Tags: xml, hadoop, hive

My XML file has the following structure.

```html
<records>
    <record customer_id=0001>
      <msg>
        <demographics gender=F agecat=1 edcat=1 jobcat=2 empcat=2 retire=0 jobsat=1 marital=1 spousedcat=1 residecat=4 homeown=0 hometype=2 addresscat=2/>
        <demographics gender=F agecat=3 edcat=5 jobcat=2 empcat=0 retire=0 jobsat=3 marital=2 spousedcat=1 residecat=4 homeown=0 hometype=3 addresscat=2/>
      .....
      </msg>
    </record>
</records>
```

I want to the final result to look like in Hive

```
0001 F 1 1 2 2 0 1 1 1 4 0 2 2
0001 F 3 5 2 0 0 3 2 1 4 0 3 2
0001 ....
0001 ....
```

I tried something like the following.

```
add jar /usr/lib/hue/hivexmlserde-1.0.0.0.jar;

CREATE external TABLE pbp (
  gender string, agecat int, edcat int, jobcat int, empcat int, retire int, jobsat int, spousedcat int, homeown int, hometype int, addresscat int
  )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  "column.xpath.gender"="/demographics/@gender",
  "column.xpath.agecat"="/demographics/@agecat",
  "column.xpath.edcat"="/demographics/@edcat",
  "column.xpath.jobcat"="/demographics/@jobcat",
  "column.xpath.empcat"="/demographics/@empcat",
  "column.xpath.retire"="/demographics/@retire",
  "column.xpath.jobsat"="/demographics/@jobsat",
  "column.xpath.spousedcat"="/demographics/@spousedcat",
  "column.xpath.homeown"="/demographics/@homeown",
  "column.xpath.hometype"="/demographics/@hometype",
  "column.xpath.addresscat"="/demographics/@addresscat",
  )
STORED AS
INPUTFORMAT 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  "xmlinput.start"="<demographics",
  "xmlinput.end"="/>"
);
```

However, I can't figure out how to insert the same customer_id value in another column in creating the pbp table. Please also suggest what I am doing is in the right direction since I am a new to this environment. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever make progress on this?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, If in case you are still looking for an answer then We have to change Start and End tags from to start from 'record tag' itself instead 'demographics tag' and consume the data as array of string. I have modified your create statement below,

```
add jar /usr/lib/hue/hivexmlserde-1.0.0.0.jar;

CREATE external TABLE pbp (
  customer_id string, gender ARRAY<string>, agecat ARRAY<int>, edcat ARRAY<int>, jobcat ARRAY<int>, empcat ARRAY<int>, retire ARRAY<int>, jobsat ARRAY<int>, spousedcat ARRAY<int>, homeown ARRAY<int>, hometype ARRAY<int>, addresscat ARRAY<int>
  )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  "column.xpath.customer_id"="/record/@customer_id",
  "column.xpath.gender"="/record/msg/demographics/@gender",
  "column.xpath.agecat"="/record/msg/demographics/@agecat",
  "column.xpath.edcat"="/record/msg/demographics/@edcat",
  "column.xpath.jobcat"="/record/msg/demographics/@jobcat",
  "column.xpath.empcat"="/record/msg/demographics/@empcat",
  "column.xpath.retire"="/record/msg/demographics/@retire",
  "column.xpath.jobsat"="/record/msg/demographics/@jobsat",
  "column.xpath.spousedcat"="/record/msg/demographics/@spousedcat",
  "column.xpath.homeown"="/record/msg/demographics/@homeown",
  "column.xpath.hometype"="/record/msg/demographics/@hometype",
  "column.xpath.addresscat"="/record/msg/demographics/@addresscat",
  )
STORED AS
INPUTFORMAT 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  "xmlinput.start"="<record",
  "xmlinput.end"="/record>"
);
```

Later you have to use POSEXPLODE the array to have the denormalized view of the data line by line along with customer_id assuming gender attribute is mandatory for all demographics.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pbp_denormalized STORED AS <FILE_FORMAT> AS
SELECT
customer_id, n.gender, agecat[pos] AS agecat, edcat[pos] AS edcat, jobcat[pos] AS jobcat, empcat[pos] AS empcat, retire[pos] AS retire, jobsat[pos] AS jobsat, spousedcat[pos] AS spousedcat, homeown[pos] AS homeown, hometype[pos] AS hometype, addresscat[pos] AS addresscat
FROM pbp
LATERAL VIEW POSEXPLODE(gender) n AS pos, gender;
```

The above code should get you the desired results.